# JHipster microservices cloudfoundry deployment error

Tags: spring, jhipster, cloud-foundry, jhipster-registry

I have the following exception when deploying to cloud with cloudfoundry. 
This is started hapening with any jhipster deployment. Same error even when deploying jhipster-registry application to cloud.

Applications run locally without error.

> 2017-11-11T13:40:10.75+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2017-11-11 10:40:10.748  WARN 12 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'allowLinkingEmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/cloudfoundry/container/customizer/boot1/AllowLinkingAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/Context
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.54+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2017-11-11 10:40:11.535  WARN 12 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'allowLinkingEmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/cloudfoundry/container/customizer/boot1/AllowLinkingAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/Context
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at io.github.jhipster.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp.main(JHipsterRegistryApp.java:75)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/Context
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    ... 21 common frames omitted
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:206)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:125)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    ... 32 common frames omitted
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2017-11-11 10:40:11.661 ERROR 12 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:992)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.Context
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:187)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:11.66+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
>   2017-11-11T13:40:12.19+0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
>   2017-11-11T13:40:12.22+0300 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have something todo with the following commits few days ago

[Buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/commit/1d37b9c042f8d7a141629875065f07185b498daf)

[Customizer](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-container-customizer/commit/8c71d38325f0185ece56e6647d479bdf3efc0f39#diff-d2f166a891659e0bbab7a531bec74e27)

I fixed it for now by changing the the buildpack url to include **#v3.19.2** in **/deploy/cloudfoundry/manifest.yml** to use the version before that change, to use the old customizer

```
buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#v3.19.2
```